# How to set up Apache2 and PHP-FPM via unix socket?

Tags: php, apache, sockets, docker, docker-compose

I try to set up Apache2 and PHP-FPM via unix socket but result is

(111)Connection refused: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock (*) failed

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
    php:
        build: "php:7.2-rc-alpine"
        container_name: "php"
        volumes:
            - "./code:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"
            - "./php7.2-fpm.sock:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock"
    apache2:
        build: "httpd:2.4-alpine"
        container_name: "apache2"
        volumes:
            - "./code:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"
            - "./php7.2-fpm.sock:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock"
        ports:
            - 80:80
        links:
            - php
```

www.conf

```
listen = /run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock
```

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
</FilesMatch>
```

But it's work when connect via TCP.

www.conf

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://php:9000"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: do you see the socket file being created on host?

Comment: Yes and all apache, php use uid and gid 500 to process. same as owner of php7.2-fpm.sock

Comment: Can you please provide a sample repo that i can test

Comment: https://github.com/overbid/apache2-php.git

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okie, so have the repo helped to fix the issue.

**Issue #1 - www.conf being copied in apache container**

You had below statement in your apache container Dockerfile

```
COPY ./www.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```

This is actually intended for the php container which will be running php-fpm and not the apache container

**Issue #2 - Socket was never being created**

Your volume bind `- "./php7.2-fpm.sock:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock"` was creating the socket and they were not being created by php-fpm as such. So you created a blank file and trying to connect to it won't do anything

**Issue #3 - No config in php to create socket**

The docker container by default create listen to `0.0.0.0:9000` inside the fpm container. You needed to override the `zz-docker.conf` file inside the container to fix the issue.

#### zz-docker.conf

```
[global]
daemonize = no

[www]
listen = /run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock
listen.mode = 0666
```

Updated docker file

```
FROM php:7.2-rc-fpm-alpine

LABEL maintainer="Eakkapat Pattarathamrong (overbid@gmail.com)"
RUN docker-php-ext-install \
        sockets

RUN set -x \
        && deluser www-data \
        && addgroup -g 500 -S www-data \
        && adduser -u 500 -D -S -G www-data www-data

COPY php-fpm.d /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/
```

**Issue #4 - Sockets being shared as volumes to host**

You should be sharing sockets using a named volume, so the socket should not be on host at all.

Updated docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
    php:
        build: "./php"
        container_name: "php"
        volumes:
            - "./code:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"
            - "phpsocket:/run/php"
    apache2:
        build: "./apache2"
        container_name: "apache2"
        volumes:
            - "./code:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"
            - "phpsocket:/run/php"
        ports:
            - 7080:80
        links:
            - php
volumes:
  phpsocket:
```

After fixing all the issues I was able to get the php page working

[image: PHP-FPM]

Comment: Thx for answers, I just add zz-docker.conf to php and everything is work.
ps. my listen.mode is 0666

Comment: Yes actually `x` permission is not needed on socket. It should be `0666` only, its bad on my part